# Does useSelector automatically unsubscribe the component from store updates when it is unmounted?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was looking through the source code for `useSelector` as part of the react-redux library.

I was wondering if `useSelector` automatically unsubscribes components from redux store updates when the component unmounts, similar to using the `unsubscribe` function returned by calling `store.subscribe` in Redux? Or if another component changes that piece of state, will this still be subscribed to such changes?

Comment: Yes it will, the callback passed to useSelector will no longer be called when a new state is created and no updates on the component will be done by react-redux when the component unmounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `useSelector` explicitly unsubscribes from the store when the component unmounts.  Per https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v7.2.2/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L81 :

```js
  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    function checkForUpdates() {
      try {
        const newSelectedState = latestSelector.current(store.getState())

        if (equalityFn(newSelectedState, latestSelectedState.current)) {
          return
        }

        latestSelectedState.current = newSelectedState
      } catch (err) {
        // we ignore all errors here, since when the component
        // is re-rendered, the selectors are called again, and
        // will throw again, if neither props nor store state
        // changed
        latestSubscriptionCallbackError.current = err
      }

      forceRender()
    }

    subscription.onStateChange = checkForUpdates
    subscription.trySubscribe()

    checkForUpdates()

    return () => subscription.tryUnsubscribe() // unsubscribes here
  }, [store, subscription])
```