# How to unsubscribe to Redux store when using the useSelector in react FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I had a single reducer big store and that store is use by multiple page and only one page is rendered at a time so if we change something on the state then other un-mounted page will be updated or Not??

if yes how to prevent that. if No then Does useSelector automatically unsubscribe the component from store updates when it is unmounted.

info : using same selector callback on every page just selecting the hole state. and using  reduxjs/toolkit

found on similar question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537456/does-useselector-automatically-unsubscribe-the-component-from-store-updates-when)

But No Mention on react-redux docs or any where else on web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useSelector` only subscribes to the state while a component is mounted. It unsubscribes as soon as your component unmounts.

Comment: Can give the any reference on the docs. or any material to read on that.

Comment: You can look at the source code: React-Redux uses `useSyncExternalStore`, which has a unsubscribe callback that we use. Or you can just believe me, I am a Redux maintainer. Generally, we did never document anything like this, because any other behaviour wouldn't make any sense. If you would have to manually clean up on component unmount, it would be very fat and red in the documentation.